# How to add 2% extra in total when some one select amazon payment as payment method!

Tags: payment, html, script

I have installed [CS extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-and-pay-with-amazon-advanced-payment-apis-for-europe.html) for Amazon payment, but I want to add a surcharge when someone selects this method.

I have tried few scripts but it does not work, installed few extension but it does not seem to work either.

any idea how to apply this extra 2% only when someone selects this method? (not other methods)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/), it explains how to add extra fee to your cart/order.

You can get your payment method from your adress like this :

```
$payment_method = $address->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();
```

Comment: hi, no i didnt lol, didnt thought of that. will try and update you here. thanks for your time.

Comment: hi, it does not give any option to add more in total in "action section" if i type discount by= +2% it changes to "2" but it self, so dont think it will increase the price.

Comment: Oups sorry I thought It was native but it seems to be a customization on my side :/ I'm looking for another solution and keep you in touch

Comment: I updated my answer, tell me what you think about it